# xhdpi image displaying for mdpi/ldpi etc

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I happen to have an image "abc.jpg" in xhdpi. and I am not using it elsewhere( mdpi/ldpi/hdpi).However, when I retrieve it through code, it seems to be pullign the same image upon reference. So, my question is do I need to add images in hdpi/mdpi etc. to pull the images with respective resolutions and If I don't add the respective image in these folders, does it pull from xhdpi by default?

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my question is do I need to add images in hdpi/mdpi etc. to pull
>   the images with respective resolutions

yes you have.  If you put a resoucerse only inside the xhdpi folder, that one will be used for every screen density